# Java spring boot - returning a json response

Tags: java, json, spring

I want to create a custom json response for a new Java Spring Boot application. At the moment I just want to create a dummy json object -- to start controlling the structure of the output json response.

When I do this it wants to create cast prefixes to the .puts -- I used to use Mongodb -- BasicDBObject -- but now I've not got mongo here.

```
 DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
 obj.put( "foo", "bar" );
```

what do I do instead?

--

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
public ResponseEntity<?> login(
        @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email,
        @RequestParam(value="password", required=false, defaultValue="password") String password, 
        HttpServletRequest request
        ) throws  Exception {

                Object response = new Object();
                    response.put("information", "test");
                    response.put("id", 3);
                    response.put("name", "course1");

                return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Comment: It's best to use a meaningful object, but you could return a `Map`.

Comment: _ a hash map? I installed the dependency --- json-simple --- JSONObject response = new JSONObject(); response.put("name", "mkyong.com"); response.put("age", new Integer(100));

Comment: I think this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839753/returning-json-object-as-response-in-spring-boot will help you.

Answer (score -2):

```
**@ResetController**   // add this
public class YourClass{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(){
        Object response = new Object();
                    response.put("information", "test");
                    response.put("id", 3);
                    response.put("name", "course1");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
     }
}
```

Comment: You mean "@RestController" -- it says its disallowed at this location.

Comment: I have installed the dependency  <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>  --  to get it working with 
         JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
          response.put("name", "mkyong.com");
             response.put("age", new Integer(100));