# returning json response in @ResponseBody spring annotation

Tags: json, spring, tomcat

i have a method returning json object. I have used annotation based configuration and annotated the method as @ResponseBody. I get the correct output if i return the object as a string. But i need the json formatted object to be returned. Since I'm new to spring I'm stuck fixing this error

> > HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error Type Exception Report
>
> Message No converter found for return value of type: class
>   org.json.simple.JSONObject
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No
>   converter found for return value of type: class
>   org.json.simple.JSONObject
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:218)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:182)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
>   logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.10
>   How do i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried just returning the original object? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839753/returning-json-object-as-response-in-spring-boot

Comment: i tried returning original object which is a json object. I got this error returning json object.

Comment: Are you building that JSONObject? It would be good to include a code snippet if you can.

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
 ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
   while(rs.next())  
   {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("id",product.getId());
    obj.put("name", product.getName());
    jsonArray.add(obj);
   }
   json.put("Emp",jsonArray);

Comment: Why dont you just return a dto?

Comment: Yeah a dto or do like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44839954/9705485

Comment: Do you have `jackson` in your dependencies ?

Comment: yea i have jackson in dependency