# why is Spring Boot returning a string instead of JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

According to this question, my method should be sending a JSON object via Jackson:

[Returning JSON object as response in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839753/returning-json-object-as-response-in-spring-boot)

But I am receiving a string at the client.

Here's the relevant parts:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class AuthController {

 @PostMapping("/api/signup")
    public String signup(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
      return "{'status':'fail', 'message':'foo'}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Crap, I think it doesn't like the single quotes.

Comment: As a side note, _don't reinvent HTTP_. If the signup failed, _return an error code_ (400, 422, 5xx) with a message, not `OK` with "no, I didn't really mean OK". `ResponseEntity` is your friend here.

Comment: Json does't have single quotes, either correct the format, or you can also use `Map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you were right about single quotes, you can achieve the JSON response without using DTO if you don't want to. You can try this:

```
@PostMapping("/api/signup")
public ResponseEntity signup(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(<http_status>)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body("{\"status\":\"fail\", \"message\":\"foo\"}");
}
```

Comment: Accepted status here is irrelevant

Comment: I used double quotes and straight `return "{json}"` worked fine, but I accepted your answer because I really like the ResponseEntity possibilities you show off.

Comment: Thank you. If we don't set the response type as `application/json`, the client wouldn't interpret it properly. that is why I suggested `ResponseEntity`

Answer (score 3):

You explicitly say `return "some string";` so it does what you asked for.

Instead, you should construct an object. I would define the following class and enum:

```
public class SignupDto {
    private Status status;
    private String message;

    public SignupDto() {
    }

    public SignupDto(Status status, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public enum Status {
        FAIL,
        SUCCESS
    }        
}
```

And use it as following:

```
public SignupDto signup(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  return new SignupDto(SignupDto.Status.FAIL, "foo");
}
```

Jackson will do the serialising automatically.