# Creat a JSONObject : Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to create a `JSONObject` :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody 
  public JSONObject  Test() {

 JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
 test.put("name","caroline");
 return test;
}
```

it's giving me as a result :

```
{"map":{"name":"caroline"}}
```

But I was waiting for something like that :

```
{"name":"caroline"}
```

I don't know where is it the problem , I just followed [this exemple](https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json#jsonobject)

Answer (score 2):

I tried with your code with a sample spring boot project and I get the error,

```
No converter for [class org.json.JSONObject]
```

The reason for this error is explained clearly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842806/1237402). To reiterate the answer, JSONObject classes don't have getters and hence the error. By default spring-boot starter web dependency has Jackson web support which can convert any POJO class to JSON object. So as the answer by @süleyman-can using a POJO is the right way to handle this.

In case, you can't use a POJO class because the fields in the response will be different for each request. For example, you have to send

```
{"a": "b"}
```

for one response and

```
{"c": "d"}
```

for another response, you can always use Map<String, String> like this,

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, String> test() {
  Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<>();
  test.put("name","caroline");
  return test;
}
```

and the response would come like this,

```json
{"name":"caroline"}
```

Comment: you can find here my real problem , can you juste take a look : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394460/how-to-generate-geojson-on-spring-boot

Comment: I like this. This is veery smart. A nice workaround

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are talking about `org.json` package

If you really want to use JSONObject to create your JSON, then the following code works. It's just that you can change the return type from JSONObject to String.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String  Test() {
    JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
    test.put("name","caroline");
    return test.toString();
}
```

Comment: Ya i'm using org.json package  , you can find here my real question , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394460/how-to-generate-geojson-on-spring-boot

Comment: if i do "test.toString();" in me case my geojson will be not correct , it's will give me something that not looke like a geojson

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

1- add this dependecy in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

2- i have this class for example

```
public class Car {

private String color;
private String type;

// standard getters setters
```

}

2- Java Object to JSON

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Car car = new Car("yellow", "renault");
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("target/car.json"), car);
```

must result like it:

```
{"color":"yellow","type":"renault"}
```

3- JSON to Java Object

```
String json = "{ \"color\" : \"Black\", \"type\" : \"BMW\" }";
Car car = objectMapper.readValue(json, Car.class);
```

Comment: you can find here my real problem ,  can you juste take a look : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394460/how-to-generate-geojson-on-spring-boot

Comment: I am faced a problem like this, but it is not on the same topic, in fact, that I worked to solve it through replace function if not find solved your issues you can try this way 
good luck @work

Answer (score 0):

You can do by creating a Class

```java
class MyResponseClass {

  private String name;
    
  public MyResponseClass(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
    
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
    
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Initial:

```java
@RestController
class MyController {

   @GetMapping("/test")
   public MyResponseClass getMyResponseClass() {
   final MyResponseClass test = new MyResponseClass("caroline");
   return test;
   }
}
```

I suggest you read this article: [Building an Application with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

Comment: you can find here my real problem , you can you juste take a look : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394460/how-to-generate-geojson-on-spring-boot