# How to get integer array from Java Object?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I'm currently working on SpringBoot project. Here is my question,
I get a `Object` type response

```
Object response = client.postForEntity(compilerUrl, params, JSONObject.class).getBody();
```

and the result is

```
{"A":"[2.0, 502.0]"}
```

How could I get the array `[2.0, 502.0]`?
I tried to use `((Map) response).get("A")`, but it still returns an `Object`.

Comment: Check out Jackson Json library

Comment: Is the response expected to be a JSON response?

Comment: Yes, it's a JSON reseponse.

Comment: Then why don't you try JSONObject class rather than Object! if you do so it is easy to get the array by typing JSONArray arr = response.getJSONArray("A");

Comment: Check out this, definitely important to get deeper details! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839753/returning-json-object-as-response-in-spring-boot